# Using Detox as Black Box tester

Tags: detox

I understand detox is a grey-box framework, but while going through iOS setup I see that the detox config is:

"binaryPath": "ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/HelloWorld.app",
        "build": "xcodebuild -project ios/example.xcodeproj -scheme example -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ios/build",
        "type": "ios.simulator",
        "name": "iPhone 7"

So my question is Can I run Detox test on .app or .apk without integrating it in app first?

Say like appium I give it apk location and run test ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how Detox works. You don't have to integrate it in your project. Just provide the .app's location in package.json.

Comment: How will the synchronization work here. As when we say Detox is grey box it knows about internal state of app to synchronize automatically. Will this be still the case in black box test?